# How can I know the functionality of Eclipse packages?

Tags: eclipse, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using JaCoCo to measure code coverage from Eclipse (Mars). As a result, I have the reports where I can see the percentage of code coveraged in the test from each Eclipse package. I want to know where can I look for the functionality from each these packages, and what does de code inside them do. The final purpose is to improve the code coverage achieved. It would be great if someone could tell me where can I find this information. The packages are:

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards

org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards

org.apache.maven.index

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.preferences

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.dialogs

org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.utils

org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.universal

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.actions

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.components

org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.rcp.news

org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog

org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.operations

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.editing

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.preferences.launch

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.search.util

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.views

org.slf4j.helpers

org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui

org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.console

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.util

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.views.build

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.views.nodes

org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.rcp

org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.universal.util

org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui

org.slf4j

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.lifecyclemapping

org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.universal.contentdetect

org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.rcp.l10n

org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.markers

org.eclipse.m2e.workspace

org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.project

org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.util

org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal

org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.internal

org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.actions

org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.rcp.preferences

Thanks

Comment: This is way, way too broad. The Eclipse source which can be found at https://git.eclipse.org/c/ you can find all the org.eclipse packages there.

Comment: You can find a package list in the Eclipse Help contents at [`Platform Plug-in Developer Guide -> Reference -> API Reference`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Foverview-summary.html).